# NavigationLink calling destination multiple times

Tags: swift, swiftui

While having a NavigationLink set-up like so in Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a):

```
NavigationView { 
  vm.isShowingBarCharts ? Text("Charts") : Text("List")
}.navigationBarItems(
                NavigationLink(destination: LEditView(vm: LEditViewModel())) {
                    LIcons.addEntry
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }
)
```

vm.isShowingBarCharts being a Published of type Bool, the view gets re-drawn (as expected) if vm.isShowingBarCharts gets flipped. What I don't understand is, why multiple LEditViewModel() instances are getting instantiated?

How that can be avoided?

Comment: Don't use `NavigationLink` in navigation bar - only inside `NavigationView`

Comment: Moving the button out of .navigationBarItems()  did not change anything.

Comment: it is also weird that the viewmodel is initialized when the parent view is created and never released (for example on the back button click). Can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: @Asperi here is an example project. https://github.com/andriansergheev/BrokenNavigationLinkSwiftUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Xcode 12.1(12A7403) iOS 14.0 + this can be fixed by using the @StateObject property wrapper.
If not using @StateObject, the VM will be instantiated every time the parent is re-drawn.

Answer (score -1):

I was using Timer Publisher which was causing each time redraw view and each second view was being navigated.
So, I need to cancel Timer Publisher when the view is about to Navigate to the next view.

```
viewModel.cancellable?.cancel()
```

Helps me to solve the issue, where `viewModel.cancellable` is `Combine`'s `Cancellable`.